# Fibonacci method return nth number in sequence

Tags: java, loops, methods, return, fibonacci

I need to make a method that returns the nth integer in the fibonacci series, the code that I wrote returns every second integer from the series when printed in a table. The int fib used in the method is the row number multiplied by the column number, could you guys help?

```
private int fibonacci(int fib){
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    while(a < fib){
        b+=a+=b;
    }
    return b+=a+=b;
}

private int fibonacci(int fib){
    int fibn = 0;

    fibn =(int)((Math.pow((1+Math.sqrt(5)), fib)-Math.pow((1-Math.sqrt(5)), fib))/(Math.pow(2,  fib)*Math.sqrt(5)));

    return fibn;
}



   *    |   1   2   3   4   5
--------------------------------
   1    |   1   1   2   3   5
   2    |   1   3   8  21  55
   3    |   2   8  34 144 610
   4    |   3  21 144 9876765
```

Comment: Why not use [Binet's Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html)?

Comment: thanks that got me closer but I need to change the value of int fib because right now in the table the series reprints one number later in the series

Comment: What is exactly your problem, because you can find plenty of implementation of fibonacci on internet, so I supposed that you want something more. But it's not transparent in your post.

Comment: I need to use this in a table to print out the fibonacci series in my table but I cannot get them to print continuously, they restart one number later in the series, I added my method and printed table to my code so you can see

Comment: I figured it out, I just need to use a count variable rather than the row*column, I dont know why I didn't think of that earlier, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code, for example:

```
public class Fibonacci {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 15, a = 1, b = 1;
        System.out.print(a + " " + b);
            for(int i =3; i < n; i++) {
            b = a + b;
            a = b - a;
            System.out.print(" " + b);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the output:

```
1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377
```